# Do you break SRP if you overwrite a method from the base class and introduce new functionality?

Tags: c#, solid-principles, single-responsibility-principle

For example.

Look at this class hierarchy:

```
public abstract class CharacterEquipment
{
    protected abstract void RunBeforeAttachProcedure();
    protected abstract void AttachToCharacter();
    protected abstract void PlayEquipEffects();

    public void Equip()
    {
        RunBeforeAttachProcedure();
        AttachToCharacter();
        PlayEquipEffects();
    }
}

public abstract class CharacterBackEquipment : CharacterEquipment
{
    protected override void AttachToCharacter()
    {
        // Attach procedure that never changes for the back.
    }
}

public class CharacterJetpack : CharacterBackEquipment
{
    protected override void RunBeforeAttachProcedure()
    {
        // Position jetpack so it is at the right position to attach to the character's back
        // There can be other equipments that you can attach to the character's back like a normal backpack which would need slightly different positioning and rotation
    }

    protected override void PlayEquipEffects()
    {
        // Play jetpack equip sounds and particle effects
    }

    public void ActivateThrusters(float force)
    {
        // This is new functionality introduced, now the equipped jetpack can fly
    }
}
```

Does this count as breaking single responsibility principle? As in the jetpack class, even though functionality is inherited and ovewritten, you are mixing equipping and flying responsibilities, correct?

Comment: The question is whether you think the equipping and flying features will vary independently. In the SRP, a responsibility is an axis of change. Several features that change for the same reasons are a single responsibility. Will these features change for different reasons?

Comment: @jaco0646 so if I want to change how the jetpack flies, thats one reason. If i want to change how it equips, its another reason? What would be two features that change for the same reasons in this case for example?